# How to retrieve child nodes data in firebase by php

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve child nodes data and update values in firebase:

[image]

As I want to make an API in which I create parameters to pass values by it.

Like example I have one node in firebase name as users and under it has user amount is 10. I want to get that data of amount from users node and add some value with it like 10+5 will update in database as 15 in my firebase.

I tried to retrieve data from firebase by seeing youtube, but I'm unable to get what I want; I was only able to get the whole users node data at whole.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a 2-step process:

1. Store the value as a number rather than as a string like you now have it.
2. Then use the [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) operation to increment it by 5.